# Java programming project

Tags: java, subclass

I am in the middle of a university project, the task being to use a scanner to read the appropriate data of several data files. The project involves a superclass and several subclasses. So far the method below works perfectly and reads data corresponding to a class called `Tool` and all its fields. However I have recently added a subclass `ElectricTool` which extends class `Tool` and also which has introduced two new fields which need reading in the same way as before but within the same method shown below. I have tried a number of things but I can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions? Preferably as clean/simple code as possible, I think it needs to be a read statement but I am struggling. The method is below:

```
public void readToolData()

{
    Frame myFrame = null;
    FileDialog fileBox = new FileDialog(myFrame,"Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fileBox.setVisible(true);
    String directoryPath = fileBox.getDirectory();
    String fileName = fileBox.getFile();

    File dataFile = new File(fileName);
    System.out.println(fileName +"  "+ directoryPath);
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try
    {
        scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    while( scanner.hasNextLine() )
    {
        String lineOfText = scanner.nextLine().trim().replaceAll("\\s+","");
        if(!lineOfText.isEmpty() && !lineOfText.matches("^//.*") && !lineOfText.substring(0,1).equals("["))
        {
            System.out.println(lineOfText);      
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }

        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(lineOfText).useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");
        while(scanner2.hasNext())
        {
            Tool tool = new Tool();
            tool.readData(scanner2);


            storeToolList(tool);
        }

    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

[electric tool class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9UMg.png)

[tool class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oum13.png)

[data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8EB9.png)

[image: reading data]

[image: terminal window after new code]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show the implementation of the `Tool` and  `ElecticToll`?

Comment: Notes: 1) to test the beginning of the string you can use `startsWith()` method, it's faster and simplier: `if(!lineOfText.isEmpty() && !lineOfText.startsWith("//") && !lineOfText.startsWith("["))`.  2) Use try with resources to open the scanner. `try(scanner = new Scanner(datafile)) { your code }`. No need to explicitly close it after.

Now to your question: how do you know what type of tool to instantiate when you read a line from a file? Is there some special marker like the name/type of the tool?

Comment: So basically, my scanner can currently read the field above in the image of my tool class, all 6 fields and print them to the terminal via a separate method. But since I have added the electrictool subclass which introduces 2 new fields I need my readtooldata method to read in the 2 extra fields.

Comment: Is every tool in the file an electric tool? If not, then how you distinguish lines corresponding to electric tools from lines corresponding to other types of tools?

Comment: all data corresponding to electric tools only is preceded by "[" and I have used if(!lineOfText.isEmpty() && !lineOfText.startsWith("//") && !lineOfText.startsWith("[")) for that. Unless I have made a mistake here? I will provide an image of the data file I am talking about

Comment: the `readToolData()` method which you have shown is a method of Tool class or ElectricTool class?

Comment: this method is part of a different class Shop

Comment: Ok, you need to create an instance of ElectricTool, not Tool. So, change `Tool tool = new Tool();` to `ElectricTool tool = new ElectricTool();` After that implement method readData in ElectricTool so that it reads data from scanner and sets all the fields.

Comment: like this?  ElectricTool tool = new ElectricTool();
                tool.readData(scanner2);
                
               

                storeToolList(tool);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public void readToolData() {
    Frame myFrame = null
    FileDialog fileBox = new FileDialog(myFrame, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fileBox.setVisible(true);
    String directoryPath = fileBox.getDirectory();
    String fileName = fileBox.getFile();

    File dataFile = new File(directoryPath + fileName);
    System.out.println(fileName + "  " + directoryPath);
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
      scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    // Current tool type
    String toolType = null;
    while( scanner.hasNextLine() ) {
      String lineOfText = scanner.nextLine().trim();

      // Skip empty lines and commentaries
      if(lineOfText.isEmpty() || lineOfText.startsWith("//")) {
        continue;
      }

      if (lineOfText.startsWith("[")) {
        // Extract the tool type name
        String withoutBracket = lineOfText.substring(1);
        // Split by spaces and take the first word
        String[] words = withoutBracket.split(" ");
        toolType = words[0];
        System.out.println("Reading information about " + toolType);
        continue;
      }

      System.out.println(lineOfText);

      Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(lineOfText).useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");
      Tool tool = null;
      if ("ElectricTool".equals(toolType)) {
        tool = new ElectricTool();
      }
      // In the future here will come more cases for different types, e.g.:
      // else if ("HandTool".equals(toolType)) {
      //    tool = new HandTool();
      // }
      if (tool != null) {
        tool.readData(scanner2);
        storeToolList(tool);
      }
    }
    scanner.close();
  }
```

Remove `scanner.skip` line in Tool.readData:

```
public class Tool {

  public void readData(Scanner scanner) {
   toolName = scanner.next(); 
   itemCode = scanner.next(); 
   timesBorrowed = scanner.nextInt(); 
   onLoan = scanner.nextBoolean(); 
   cost = scanner.nextInt(); 
   weight = scanner.nextInt(); 
   scanner.skip(".*");   // Remove this line  
  }

}
```

And implement readTool method in ElectricTool:

```
 @Override
 public void readData(Scanner scanner) {
   super.readData(scanner);
   rechargeable = scanner.nextBoolean();
   power = scanner.next(); // Or nextInt? what is the type of power field?
 }
```

To print the information about the tools you should use polymorphism.
Modify your printAllTools method in Shop.java like this:

```
public void printAllTools() {
  System.out.println("Information");
  System.out.println("---------->");
  for (Tool t : toolList) {
    System.out.println("You have selected:\n");
    t.printDetails();
  }
}
```

Now, your method printDetails in Tool.java must be looking like this:

```
public void printDetails() {
  System.out.println("Tool name: " + toolName + "\n" +
    "Item code: " + itemCode + "\n" +
    "Times borrowed: " + timesBorrowed + "\n" +
    "On load: " + onLoan + "\n" + 
    "Cost: " + cost + "\n" +
    "Weight: " + weight + "g\n"
  );
}
```

and in the ElectricTool.java:

```
public void printDetails() {
  super.printDetails();
  System.out.println("Rechargeable: " + rechargeable + "\n" +
   "Power: " + power + "\n"
  );
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209119/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-java-programming-project).